# make the loop more efficient and faster in r

Tags: r

I made the following code for data
It works fine, but the problem is that it takes too long as my dataset is huge.
Could someone make the code more efficient and faster?
Thanks a lot in advance!

```
for (f in 1: nlevels(try$IDISIN)) {
  temp<-subset(try, IDISIN==levels(try$IDISIN)[f])
  temp<-as.data.table(temp)
  temp2<-temp %>%
    arrange(TradingDate) 
  temp2<-as.data.table(temp2)

  
  for (i in 1:nrow(temp2)) {
    temp2$CSum[i]<-ifelse(i=="1", temp2$Dailysum[1],(temp2$CSum[i-1] + temp2$Dailysum[i]))
    if (temp2$CSum[i]<0) {
      Selling<-bind_rows(Selling, temp2[i])
      temp2$CSum[i]<-0
    }
    temp2$CSum[i]<-ifelse(temp2$FinalInd[i]==1, 
                          temp2$CSum[i]/temp2$A.Factor[i], 
                          temp2$CSum[i])
    
    
  }
  Rebind<-bind_rows(Rebind, temp2) 
  rm(list = "temp", "temp2")
}
```

and here is simplified dataset

```
try<- data.frame(ISIN=c("abc", "abc", "ghi", "def", "def", "def", "ghi", "ghi", "ghi"),
                  ID =c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"),
                  TradingDate=c("2022-07-01", "2022-07-02", "2022-07-03", "2022-07-01", "2022-07-02", "2022-07-03","2022-07-01", "2022-07-02", "2022-07-03"),
                  Dailysum=c("-4", "8", "1", "2", "-6","9", "4", "8", "9"),
                  A.Factor=c("0", "0", "0.1", "0", "0","0", "0", "0.5", "0"),
                  Ind=c("0", "0", "1", "0", "0","0", "0", "1", "0"))
library(data.table)
try<-as.data.table(try)
try[,IDISIN:=paste(ISIN, ID,sep = "-")]
Selling<-try[is.na(ISIN)]
Rebind<-try[is.na(ISIN)]


  ISIN ID TradingDate Dailysum A.Factor Ind IDISIN
1:  abc  A  2022-07-01       -4        0   0  abc-A
2:  abc  A  2022-07-02        8        0   0  abc-A
3:  ghi  A  2022-07-03        1      0.1   1  ghi-A
4:  def  B  2022-07-01        2        0   0  def-B
5:  def  B  2022-07-02       -6        0   0  def-B
6:  def  B  2022-07-03        9        0   0  def-B
7:  ghi  C  2022-07-01        4        0   0  ghi-C
8:  ghi  C  2022-07-02        8      0.5   1  ghi-C
9:  ghi  C  2022-07-03        9        0   0  ghi-C
```

I need to do following things

1. cumulative sum by ISIN and ID
2. If cumulatvie sume is negative

   1. save it into seperate dataframe ("Selling" in the above code)
   2. set cumulative sum to 0
3. If Ind=1, divide cumulative sum with Factor

So it should look like this

```
dat <- data.frame(ISIN=c("abc", "abc", "ghi", "def", "def", "def", "ghi", "ghi", "ghi"),
                  ID =c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"),
                  TradingDate=c("2022-07-01", "2022-07-02", "2022-07-03", "2022-07-01", "2022-07-02", "2022-07-03","2022-07-01", "2022-07-02", "2022-07-03"),
                  Dailysum=c("-4", "8", "1", "2", "-6","9", "4", "8", "9"),
                  A.Factor=c("0", "0", "0.1", "0", "0","0", "0", "0.5", "0"),
                  Ind=c("0", "0", "1", "0", "0","0", "0", "1", "0"),
                  CSum= c("0", "8", "10", "2", "0","9", "4", "24", "33"))

  ISIN ID       Date Quantity Factor Ind CumulativeSum
1  abc  A 2022-07-01       -4      0   0             0
2  abc  A 2022-07-02        8      0   0             8
3  ghi  A 2022-07-03        1    0.1   1            10
4  def  B 2022-07-01        2      0   0             2
5  def  B 2022-07-02       -6      0   0             0
6  def  B 2022-07-03        9      0   0             9
7  ghi  C 2022-07-01        4      0   0             4
8  ghi  C 2022-07-02        8    0.5   1            24
9  ghi  C 2022-07-03        9      0   0            33
```

Comment: What should `Selling` look like? FYI, your top code block fails to run, your `temp2$CSum` is at fault.

Comment: Why are all of your numbers strings??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't run your first code block, so I don't know for certain what `Selling` should look like, but I think we can do it as part of the main processing and then you can filter it out later.

First, I think many of those columns should be numbers, so

```r
try[, names(try) := lapply(.SD, type.convert, as.is = TRUE)]
str(try)
# Classes 'data.table' and 'data.frame':    9 obs. of  6 variables:
#  $ ISIN       : chr  "abc" "abc" "ghi" "def" ...
#  $ ID         : chr  "A" "A" "A" "B" ...
#  $ TradingDate: chr  "2022-07-01" "2022-07-02" "2022-07-03" "2022-07-01" ...
#  $ Dailysum   : int  -4 8 1 2 -6 9 4 8 9
#  $ A.Factor   : num  0 0 0.1 0 0 0 0 0.5 0
#  $ Ind        : int  0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0
```

Second, I don't think we need `IDISIN`, since I think you're using it as an easy grouping variable, in which case `data.table`'s use of `by=` takes care of it for us.

Third, I'm *assuming* that you are controlling the order of data (`TradingDate`) externally, perhaps `setkey(try, ISIN, ID, TradingDate)` or similar. I make no checks (or promises if this is not true.) (Over to you if you want `try[, TradingDate := as.Date(TradingDate)]`, it seems logical to do so but changes nothing *here*.)

From here,

```r
fun <- function(prev, this) {
  z <- prev[1] + this[1]
  c(max(z, 0), max(-z, 0)) / (if (this[2] > 0) this[3] else 1)
}
try[, c("CumulativeSum", "Sell") :=
        transpose(Reduce(fun, transpose(list(Dailysum, Ind, A.Factor)),
                         init = c(0, 0), accumulate = TRUE)[-1]),
    by = .(ISIN, ID) ]
try
#      ISIN     ID TradingDate Dailysum A.Factor   Ind CumulativeSum  Sell
#    <char> <char>      <char>    <int>    <num> <int>         <num> <num>
# 1:    abc      A  2022-07-01       -4      0.0     0             0     4
# 2:    abc      A  2022-07-02        8      0.0     0             8     0
# 3:    ghi      A  2022-07-03        1      0.1     1            10     0
# 4:    def      B  2022-07-01        2      0.0     0             2     0
# 5:    def      B  2022-07-02       -6      0.0     0             0     4
# 6:    def      B  2022-07-03        9      0.0     0             9     0
# 7:    ghi      C  2022-07-01        4      0.0     0             4     0
# 8:    ghi      C  2022-07-02        8      0.5     1            24     0
# 9:    ghi      C  2022-07-03        9      0.0     0            33     0
```

No `for` loop required.

Admittedly, the `Sell` logic might need double-check to make sure that successive negatives will react as you need it. That should be handled in the `fun`ction. In there, the two arguments:

- `prev` are the *previous* row's values for `CumulativeSum` and `Sell`, as determined by the previous call to `fun` (within a group). The first time it is called for a group, it is preassigned the value `c(0, 0)` (by the `init=` argument).
- `this` is a triplet of the *current* row's `c(Dailysum, Ind, A.Factor)` (all numbers, not named), so we index it directly by position.

Comment: I feel like you are a genius! thanks a lot! It worked perfectly and a way faster. (with a slight change about Sell indeed).
Brilliant to use transpose. 
Still trying to figure out how "z <- prev[1] + this[1]"  works in combination with "accumulate = TRUE". Anyway your code helped me a lot. thank you again.

Comment: The default mode of `Reduce` is to return only the last iteration of the reduction; `accumulate=TRUE` means to return every step of the way, which gives us our cumulative logic (for multiple rows). That has little to do with the `z <- ...` expression, which is just adding the previous row's first value (which, if you read the trailing notes in the answer, is the previous row's `CumulativeSum`) with the current row's `Dailysum` value.